# Intellij ignores the selected keyboard layout

Tags: intellij-idea

This seems like a bug in IntelliJ 12: Every couple of times when I switch between keyboard layouts (English and Hebrew) IntelliJ get stuck on one of them and ignore the windows selected keyboard layout. This happens only for intelliJ, all other programs respond as usual to the windows selected keyboard layout.

Is there at least a workaround, or a way to reset IntelliJ's keyboard layout? The only thing that seems to work for me so far is restarting my machine...

(My OS is Windows 7 Enterprise 64bit)

Comment: There seems to be an [open bug on this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6290) , but I can't see a workaround here

Comment: It's _still_ there! Did you manage to solve the problem for you?

Comment: Same problem in Idea 13. Any solution?

Comment: Restart intellij. It is not a solution but a possible work around. I think you have already realized it.

Comment: It happens on every time I switch between applications.

Comment: Go to Windows' Control Panel -> Region and Language Settings -> Languages Tab ->
In the dialog that opens select the "Keyboard" button. You'll probably find that the
key combinations "alt+left-shift" switches the input setting. Just disable......Worked for me

Comment: Yes. Same to me on Linux switching from ABNT2 to US layout

Answer (score 26):

This is 100% reproduced when you switch keyboard layout in quick class search (Ctrl+N). Also in intellij idea 13.
Something like:

1. Open quick search menu when keyboard is not in English layout (Russian e.g.)
2. Type anything
3. Switch to English
4. Congratulations! you stuck in russian layout :) restart your intellij idea!

When I ceased to switch layout in search, I forgot about this problem.

UPD: it's suitable for most part of text inputs (even for search and file creation)

Comment: The problem is that it's still stuck after restarting.

Answer (score 20):

I've just had this problem on PyCharm 2020.2.3
Here's how I've solved it:

- Go to `Settings -> Keymap`
- At the bottom of the window, check the option `Use national layouts for shortcuts (require restart)`

That did the trick

Comment: I cant find that options in newer versions. Has it been renamed?

Comment: thank you!!! It worked for me on Linux (under gnome) + PyCharm 2022.1.3 (Professional Edition). I thing this is the official way to go

Comment: It didn't help in my case :(

Comment: Works in Android Studio 2022.3.1 on Linux GNOME!

Comment: Works in IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.2 CE on Linux Gnome.

Answer (score 5):

restarting IntelliJ also works.
I wonder how they managed to get such a stupid bug, this is not an easy bug to write, especially in Java.

Answer (score 5):

That was found to be more like a global Microsoft/Oracle bug. Simple workaround from IntelliJ's issue tracker: use Windows' language parameters to assign a hotkey (Ctrl + number) for changing the layout directly to a desired language. This suddenly will affect both Windows And IDEA. It's said that bug was fixed in Win8. A bit more info: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667947/preserving-keyboard-layout-in-swing-app)

Answer (score 5):

In 2020 bug is still relevant in the most IDEs based on IntelliJ. For example I observe this in PyCharm now.

There is **workaround** for Windows:

1. Go to Language Bar - Settings... - Advanced Key Settings
2. Set key sequence of To English action to Ctrl + 1
3. Set key sequence of to other your language to Ctrl + 2
4. Apply
5. Go to IntelliJ/PyCharm and switch language by new sequences
6. After that bug disappears and you can switch language by traditional method

Comment: You're a life-saver, works for me in Windows 10, faced the same problem in Jetbrains Rider. Keep in mind that the problem might return if you upgrading (updating) your IDE

Comment: Is there a language bar in intelliJ? where?

Answer (score 1):

For me the following actions seem to resolve the issue:

1. Go to Control Panel
2. Select Clock, Language & Region
3. Press Region
4. In the opened window choose English for Format.

Also all my settings except the location are set to English (locale, default keyboard etc.)

Answer (score 1):

This fix worked on my mac, access `Preferences` -> `Editor` -> `Typing Corrector` from the intellij IDEA menu. If you are able to navigate to the same window on your OS, you can try this.

Uncheck `Enable keyboard layout correction` in the `Typing Corrector` window

[image: Access Typing Corrector Menu in Editor]

Comment: I can't find this setting

Comment: @evening_g me neither

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue in Ubuntu 16.04. Restarting IDEA doesn't change anything. But Changing the default layout to be the one I want by default ensured ubuntu work well with it.

Comment: You mean, changing the default layout in gnome?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the search textfield above file editor.
2. Switch layout.
3. Type smth.
4. Click somwhere in the file editor.
5. Write smth with swithed layout.